# Casting programmatically through Chrome's native video player

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, google-cast

In the latest Chrome version, there is an option to cast a HTML video using the native player controls. Is there a way to do this programmatically, without having to use the Cast SDK?

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a way to do this programmatically, without having to use the Cast SDK?**

AFAIK, you still need the Cast SDK, although you'll be using the Chrome implementation in the form of [Chrome Sender Framework API](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender_setup).

> Registration
>
> Other than registering your application and device, no special setup
>   steps are required to use the Google Cast Chrome Sender SDK. As long
>   as you have the latest version of Chrome, it is possible for your web
>   content to access and use the SDK.

Check the [Integrate Cast v3 into your Chrome app](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender_integrate) guide which includes a [Cast video sample app in Chrome](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-chrome).